# Filling a dictionary with numbers from textbox and with the textboxes as keys

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I'm writing a code where I want to get the numbers from multiple `TextBox` controls into a collection. Sort it, then change the background color of the textboxes containing the top 3 highest value. This is the dictionary

```
Dictionary<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, string> all_cycles = new Dictionary<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, string>(10);
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    all_cycles.Add(((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtendc" + Convert.ToString(i), true)[0]),this.Text);
}
```

I know that with "this.text" I won't get the textboxes values so that's why I'm asking.
I also tried creating an array which only contains the values of the textboxes which I then use to fill the dictionary. But it always drops an Index was outside the bounds of the array. Or Index was out of range exception. This drops the out of range exception:

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox> txtendc = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>(10);
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    txtendc.Add((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtendc" + Convert.ToString(i), true)[0]);
}
int[] endc_content = new int[10];
for (var i = 1;i < 5; i++)
{
    endc_content[i]= int.Parse(txtendc[i].Text);
}
```

I don't have any problem with the coloring, just filling up the dictionary. If you have a better solution than the dictionary collection please tell me.
Thanks

EDIT: This whole code is inside a timer tick event if it matters anything

Comment: You can sort those textboxes based on values and then select top 3 from the list.

Comment: this actually helps but I used orderby and it did nothing.
 txtendc.OrderBy(x => x.Text).Take(3);

Comment: To sort by value, you should convert the value to int (if they are int values) and also you need to use `OrderByDescending`, like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38506414/3110834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort those `TextBox` controls based on values and then select top 3 from the list:

```
var result = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(x =>
                 {
                     try { return new { Key = x, Value = Convert.ToInt32(x.Text) }; }
                     catch { return null; }
                 })
                 .Where(x=>x!=null)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                 .Take(3)
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

To test the result, show a message box containing values:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n",
    result.Select((x, i) => string.Format("{0}:{1}", i+1, x.Value))));
```

Above example will be applied on any list of `TextBox` controls and just for example I used all `TextBox` controls of the form.

Comment: Above example will be applied on any list of `TextBox` controls and just for example I used all `TextBox` controls of the form. So you can first the `TextBox` controls which you want and then apply the same logic on them. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: I tried it in my code but when I'm displaying the values in test textboxes it only shows the 3rd value 3 times

Comment: Surely the problem is by your code, because `Take(3)` will not return an item 3 times. If you see an item 3 times, it means that item exists 3 times in the initial list which you perform query on it. To verify the code, it's enough to put some textboxes on your form and type value in some of them and run the code.

Comment: first of all do I need the code which I originally posted for this to work or I only need your code. now only your code (and the cycle to display the results) is used. added more textboxes typed values and still it only displays the 3rd value 3 times. And the other problem is that it gets the values of other textboxes too. I don't have much experience with programming. only 4 years of studying and 1 year work experience so please don't mind if I ask dumb questions

Comment: also I ran a duplicate search. There are none. This is the code I used for it.
var dupli = result.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

Comment: You should only use my code in a place like Click event of a button. I only added a simple message box for test. It shows selected top 3 values in order.

Comment: I got it to work and also change the textbox background. Another problem I got is that this method also cycles through the other textboxes which I don't want to. I tried to specify the name with x.Name.StartsWith but it doesnt work

Comment: As I said, you should use the technique on a given list of `TextBox` controls. For example `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` is all `TextBox` controls which are directly on this form, or `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=>x.Name.StartWith("some"))` is those `TextBox` control which are located directly on the form and have `"some"` in the start of their names.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a list of all of your TextBoxes in code behind when you instantiate your class.  Then you could use Linq to get the top 3.  Remember that you will need to confirm that all of the textboxes actually contain numbers - ensure that your program doesn't crash if you enter text into one of them.  If all of the TextBoxes in the form will be holding these numbers, you could do something like this to validate and sort in one method (not tested):

```
private List<TextBox> myTextBoxes { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            myTextBoxes.Add((TextBox)c);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<TextBox> getTop3()
{
    return myTextBoxes.Where(tb => tb.Text.AsEnumerable().All(char.IsDigit)).Select(tb => tb).OrderByDescending(tb => Double.Parse(tb.Text)).Take(3);
}
```

The first step of the Linq query converts the text to an enumerable of char and ensures that all characters contain digits (instead of letters).  The second selects these textboxes.  The third parses them into doubles and compares them, highest number first.  The last takes the first three in the list (the textboxes containing the highest 3 numbers)

EDIT: Based on your comments, the code could be simplified to:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

private IEnumerable<TextBox> getTop3(string textboxPrefix)
{
    List<TextBox> textBoxesToSort = new List<TextBox>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.Name.StartsWith(textboxPrefix))
            textBoxesToSort.Add((TextBox)c);

    return textBoxesToSort.OrderByDescending(tb => Double.Parse(tb.Text)).Take(3);
}
```

Comment: sorry for not writing this in the first place. the textboxes get data from a plc directly. There are multiple column of textboxes (every textbox has a different name but the ones in the same column only differ in the last character in their names). and all of the texts are digits

Comment: Please see edited answer based on comparing only textboxes with the same prefix and assuming that all entries are numeric.

Comment: how can I call it in the method I want to use it ?
I called it like this:
 getTop3("txtendc");
but I have no idea how to change the back color of the textboxes in textBoxesToSort

Comment: When you call a method like this, you get back an IEnumerable (like a list) of three textboxes and you can assign that returned list to a local variable called "textBoxes".  Then you can say something like, foreach Textbox tb in TextBoxes { tb.BackColor = Colors.Red }.  If that's all you're doing with the list, you can combine that all into one method too - the only advantage of splitting into mulitple methods is to allow you to reuse the code that selects the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, hope it helps:

```
List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox> all_cycles = new List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>(10);
        int[] indexOfTextBox = new int[3];
        foreach(var cycle in all_cycles)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt16(cycle.Text);
            if (value > indexOfTextBox[0])
            {
                indexOfTextBox[0] = value;
            }
            else if (value > indexOfTextBox[1])
            {
                indexOfTextBox[1] = value;
            }
            else if (value > indexOfTextBox[2])
            {
                indexOfTextBox[2] = value;
            }
        }
        all_cycles[indexOfTextBox[0]].BackColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        all_cycles[indexOfTextBox[1]].BackColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        all_cycles[indexOfTextBox[2]].BackColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
```

Comment: same error. index was outside the bounds of the array